# How to list post as buch of category, and all of them

Tags: posts, categories, sort

I like my homepage not to list only one category, but to list all category, group by post. Here is the request :

Cat

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

and the post will be :

post

- 1 (cat=2)
- 2(cat=2)
- 3(cat=1)
- 4(cat=3)
- 5(cat=4)
- 6(cat=4)
- 7(cat=4)
- 8(cat=4)
- 9(cat=5)

i like to list cat : 5,2,4,3,1 and when listing them, all the post from cat 5, then all the post from cat 2, and so on

So the result will be post :

- 9
- 1
- 2
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 4
- 3

hope the example is clear enough to let you help me... thanks in advance

Comment: is the category list '5,2,4,3,1' always the same, or likely to change?

Comment: the category ID dont change, but i like to get all the category in the database.... but i want to choose the order... so i have no problem to hardcode it in shortcode or php if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a general structure how I would do it:

```
$categories = array(5,2,4,3,1); //manually enter the array of the category ids in the order how you want them to appear
  foreach( $categories as $cat ) { 
    $args = array( 
      'category__in' => array( $cat ), 
      'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : while( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
//enter here, whatever you want to show per post//
    endwhile;
    endif;
  } //end of foreach
```

Comment: work perfectly.... make it as a plugin and you be famous !... here you can see it live : http://mecanomedic.com/